# Can a Custom C# object contain a property of the same type as itself?

Tags: c#, object, properties

If I have created the following **Employee** object (simplified)...

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {       
        }

        public String StaffID { get; set; }
        public String Forename { get; set; }
        public String Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

... would it be acceptable  to have another property in the **Employee** object with a Type also being **Employee** to hold their Manager's details (as shown below)?

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {       
        }

        public String StaffID { get; set; }
        public String Forename { get; set; }
        public String Surname { get; set; }

        public Employee Manager { get; set; }
    }
```

Also, what is the best way to instantiate the **Employee** object for the **Manager** property? Obviously including `this.Manager = new Employee();` in the constructor will cause an infinite loop. Would a **Manager** class that inherrits from **Employee** be the best way (even though all the properties would be identical)?

Comment: @FelixK. Thats a bit harsh, its a good question and taken some interest read this *..in the constructor will cause an infinite loop*. Remember all are not experts

Comment: @V4Vendetta That's true, we are not all experts. But when i have a problem or question i gonna test some ways to solve the task which causes the problem.

Comment: @FelixK. Yes, I did try it and it compiled fine - This is why my question was whether it was 'acceptable' rather than 'will it work' - I wanted to check whether this was good practice or not more than anything. As it happens, the solutions below regarding the instantiation of the object are pretty much what I had concluded too but again, being relatively inexperienced, I wanted to make sure that I was on track.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An object **can** indeed have a reference to an object of its own type.

This is how most `Node` type objects are implemented.

As for instantiation - you can pass in the `Employee` object to use as manager (passing in *null* for no manager). Constructors can have multiple overloads:

```
public Employee(Employee manager)
{
   this.Manager = manager;
}
```

Comment: ... but obviously you shouldn't unconditionally initialize the property/field in your constructor (since that would cause either a `StackOverflowException` or an `OutOfMemoryException`, depending on the size of the object, the allocated stack size and your overall available memory).

Comment: @Tobias The code above is not going to cause any exception. It would cause one if you initialize it with `this.Manager = new Employee()`.

Comment: The comment was meant to be directly appended to the answer (hence the ...), and I posted it before the .ctor code block was added.

Comment: -1 for the cheeky edit adding overloaded Employee constructor after @DennisTraub posted it first ;)

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson - You seem to be missing the point of the wiki like attributes of SO. As it stands, I was adding this anyways, without looking at other answers - thanks for the assumption though. And edits are supposed to make answers better - suppose I did lift it off another answer, how does that make it bad? You downvote an answer because it was made better?

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson People here are looking for better answers not for who answers them

Comment: @Oded no offence intended, however how can duplicating another person's answer after the fact add value? SO tends to close questions that are duplicates, hence my reasoning for -1. Best regards,

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson - _Questions_ are not answers. Me adding a code sample adds value in that this answer is now more complete. Again, you are making assumptions - the idea is not so novel that more than one person can think of it at one time.

Comment: @Oded sure happens to me that I post a similar answer simultaneously, so apologies for making an assumption. Regards,

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson - Last point. You seem to have a notion of fair-play that is not applicable to StackOverflow. I don't really get it.

Comment: @Oded - I think we're getting way off topic for here, but save to say fair play or sportsmanship is important in all competitive activities. Regards,

Comment: @Oded, good answer here.  I got another question regarding this which comes up naturally when I  think a little bit deeper:   what is the best practice to implemented the `IEquatable<T>` to this kind of type. The manager can have its own manager, and its like recursively compare...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, an object can contain references to other objects of the same class.

And secondly, I wouldn't create a new Employee in the cunstructor but inject it like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(Employee manager)
    {
        this.Manager = manager;
    }

    public String StaffID { get; set; }
    public String Forename { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The only scenario where this *isn't* possible is with a `struct`; a `struct` is contained **directly** (rather than being a fixed-size reference to the data), so the size of an `Employee` struct would have to be "the size of the other fields plus the size of an Employee", which is circular.

In particular you can't have:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo foo;
}
```

(or anything else that would result in a circular size) - the compiler responds with:

> Struct member 'Foo.foo' of type 'Foo' causes a cycle in the struct layout

However, in all other cases it is fine; with the issue of initialisation, I'd say: just leave it unassigned initially, and let the caller assign a value via the property.

Answer (score 2):

First, the answer is **Yes** an object can have a field that contains an instance of itself. It can even have methods that accept or return the instances of the same class, and it can even depend on itself in the definition of the class, e.g:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person> //legal, recursive definition
{
   //fields (or properties) that are of type Person
   public Person Father;
   public Person Mother;
   public List<Person> Children;

   // method that takes a Person as a parameter
   public bool IsParent(Person potentialParent)
   {
      ....
   }

   //method that returs a Person
   public Person Clone()
   {
      //TODO: real implementation coming soon
   }

   public Person(){}

   //constructor that takes persons as arguments
   public Person(Person father, Person Mother)
   {
      Father = father;
      Mother = mother;
   }
}
```

By default all reference values are `null`'d so you won't have a constructor problem unless you create one yourself. So, **Yes**, there can be some issues with circular references and endless loops (each parent has children that have children that have parents etc...) but usually they can be trivially detected and avoided.

The only times I've encountered these kind of problems is when I used XML (or other text-based) serialization on circularly referenced objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have `Employee` inside `Employee` and it will not cause infinite loop, by default `Manager` property of `Employee` object will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It works, you can just try s.th. like:

```
public class A
{
    public A test { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically on the issue of construction (I've +1'd Odeds answer) - as you say constructing an  instance in the constructor is a bad move.

But then ask yourself - why would you ever need to anyway.  In your `Manager`/`Employee` case - you can't always be sure that an employee always has a manager, and if they don't then you shouldn't be using a `new`ed empty instance to signify that, but a null.

When your type will have public get/set accessors on the properties, generally you're likely to be loading these object trees from some external source, in which case you have nothing to worry about.  Equally, you can have a constructor that accepts other `Employee` instances for Manager/Employee relationships etc.

You should also be checking for circular relationships in that constructor as well - i.e. an employee can't be someone's manager and their employee - try walking the child->parent relationship for that and see if it ever ends!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it worked for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A(new A());
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A a;

    public A() { }
    public A(A _a)
    {
        a = _a;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in the Main() function like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A(new A());
        a.Name = "Roger";
        a.a.Name = "John";
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", a.Name, a.a.Name);
    }
}
```