# why do we define a struct object from itself in the struct definition

Tags: c#, struct

in the code below, there is a struct defined. In the definition there are some structs created from itself. it comes to me like a mirror in the mirror, or calling a recursive function a recursive function. Because you are defining some variable while variable is still not defined, i mean in itself??
How does it work?
why do we use it in general? 
and what is the effect?

thanks for explanation..

```
public struct **PersonId**
{
    public static readonly **PersonId** default= new PersonId(value,1,1);
    public static readonly **PersonId** x = new PersonId(someValue, 0, 0);
    public static readonly **PersonId** y = new PersonId(someOtherVale,-1,0);

    [DataMember]
    public int Prop1 { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Prop2 { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Prop3 { get; private set; }

    public PersonId(int prop1 , int prop2 , int prop3 )
        : this()
    {
        Prop1 = prop1 ;
        Prop2 = prop2 ;
        Prop3 = prop3 ;
    }
```

Comment: OP: I think you need to focus your question more... Like what don't you get? For a start you compare it to recursive functions which are also perfectly allowed and I've never seen anybody ask how they work. Questions to help narrow down what you want to know... Are you asking what part of the spec allows it to refer to itself? Are you wanting to know how the compiler parses and processes the source code? And then you also start asking questions like "Why do we use it?" and "what is the effect" which seem to be entirely different from the how/why it works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Custom C# object contain a property of the same type as itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892703/can-a-custom-c-sharp-object-contain-a-property-of-the-same-type-as-itself)

Comment: Why does it matter in your mind where the static field is declared? It's **static**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a `static` as a global variable - you are effectively declaring `default` and `x` and `y` as global variables (*).

If you **couldn't** do this, how would you expect something like `DateTime.MinValue` to work?

```
public static readonly DateTime MinValue = new DateTime(0L, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Note that your code won't compile if you removed the `static` as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892920/34092 .

*(*) Not strictly speaking true, but stick with me for now.*

Comment: in the link that you gave, there is mentioned that "static" is not needed by classes? But when you dont use "static" word there, an Employee  will be created first. a Manager will also be created in the Employee, and when a Manager is created, another Manager in the Manager will be created. it goes so on and doesnt stop. isnt it??

public class Employee
{
    public Employee(Employee manager)
    {
        this.Manager = manager;
    }
    public String a{ get; set; }
    public String b{ get; set; }
    public String c{ get; set; }

    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}

Comment: @Wolfgang The entire point of that thread is that it only causes an infinite loop of inclusion if the self is contained as a data member by value, i.e. not as a reference or the return type of some method (static or not). If the 'containment' takes any of the latter forms, there's no problem.

Comment: @Wolfgang Your original post was about structs, not classes. If you have a question about classes then you may be best to post a new question to discuss there. _Structs and classes are quite different._

Comment: @underscore_d: your "Entire point" is correct. but "static" is not a return type as you mentioned. defining it as "static" prevent the code not make a infinit loop as mjwills explained, i think..

Comment: @Wolfgang No, I didn't say static was a return type. I said it was an attribute of a method. _"the return type of **some method (static or not)**"_ My point was that it's having the struct as a member of itself that is the problem, whereas if it has a method that returns its own type, that is OK. And it does not matter whether or not that method is static.